# How to update position of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, position

This is my first time posting here so I hope I'm doing it right. I appreciate any help I can get.

I am trying to update the position of a div using a Javascript function that, when called by the click of a button, calculates random numbers and then uses these numbers to change the position of the div. Unfortunately, clicking the button does not change the position of the div.

This is my HTML:

```
<body>

<p>Want to see something cool?</p>
<button id = "funbutton" onclick="SeeWhatHappens()">Click here!</button>

<div id = "newdiv" class="a"></div>

</body>
```

And this is my Javascript function:

```
function SeeWhatHappens() {
var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
var divsize = 50;
var posx = (Math.random() * document.width() - divsize).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * document.height() - divsize).toFixed();
var div = document.getElementById('newdiv');
div.style.left = posx;
div.style.top = posy;
}
```

Here is my full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6hnLx6qc/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly, you need to be using absolute positioning for the div in order to control its left and top positions. That may be the only issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems. The first one is that there is no such methods `width` and `height` on `document` object. You can use `window.innerWidth/innerHeight` instead. And the second one, you need to use `px` units for `style.left/top` values:

```
function SeeWhatHappens() {
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    var divsize = 50;
    var posx = (Math.random() * window.innerWidth - divsize).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * window.innerHeight - divsize).toFixed();
    var div = document.getElementById('newdiv');
    div.style.left = posx + 'px';
    div.style.top = posy + 'px';
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6hnLx6qc/7/

Comment: Thank you SO much! Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You had some issues with getting the width and height of the document.  I switched it to use `window.innerHeight` and `.innerWidth` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hnLx6qc/8/